# How do you look for a line in a text file, from a sentence a user has inputted, by using its keywords?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a=input("Please enter your problem?")
problem= ()

with open('solutions.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if problem in line:
            print (line)
```

Can someone please help me on how to get the keywords from the inputed string by the user. Thanks. I need help on how to look for some of the words the users inputed in to =a and search for them on the textfile and print the line

Comment: python 2 or 3. You have to choose (`input` won't work for you in python 2). And what do you want to find: all the keywords of `problem` or only some, one?? unclear.

Comment: your solution is correct, in will handle what you want

Comment: What is wrong with your solution?

Comment: @leaf I do not know how to get the keywords from the users input in to the variable = problem

Comment: @JoeyMcFee You already are getting user input into the `a` variable. Why do you need `problem`?

Comment: @cricket_007   Basically. I need to make a program that will ask the user its problem. The solutions are on a textfile. I need to get the program to pic the correct line depending on the users problem. I dont know how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

I assume your keywords is meant to be a list?

Then you use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to check if any word out of the keywords is in the line.

```
a=input("Please enter your problem?")
problem= ['#keywords', 'not', 'sure', 'how']

with open('solutions.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if any(word in line for word in problem):
            print (line)
```

Though, you may want to `split()` your line to improve that detection.

Otherwise, you have `a`, which stores the user's input, so you can use that.

```
a=input("Please enter your problem?")
problem= a.split()
```

Then, again `problem` is a list, so you use `any()` as before

Or, if you want to check if the entire entered value is in a line, then

```
if a in line:
    print(line)
```

Comment: Please check the code again. The problem variable is not a list. What I need the program to do is, from the users input, print the line with most of the users inputed words

Comment: There isn't a straightforward way to find the "most of the users inputed words". You can do `if a in line:` to test the entered string. I still do not see the need for the `problem` variable if it is not a list

Comment: isnt there a way to even some of the users inputed wordsand look for them in the textfile

Comment: What do you mean "even some of the words"? If I understood correctly, that is what option 2 here is showing `problem = a.split()`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood the question but is this what you want?. this will take the line containing the most words from the user input:

```
problem = a.split(' ')
max_num, current_num = 0,0  #max_num count the maximum apparition of words from the input in the line| current_num count the current number of apparition of words of the user input in the line
chosen_line = ''

with open('solutions.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        for word in problem:
            if word in line:
                current_num+=1
        if current_num>max_num:
            print line,max_num,current_num
            max_num=current_num
            chosen_line = line
        current_num = 0
    print chosen_line
```

but it seems to me the easiest way to do what you want is to store at the start of each answer the question, or even easier - just ask the user the question number and return this corresponding answer.

Comment: with this it just prints the top line on the text file no matter what the input from the user is

Comment: @JoeyMcFee oups! - instead of print line the last line should have been print chosen_line I'v fixed it now, does it work?